# How to get XSLX sheet latest row number and latest column number with Docx4j

Tags: java, xlsx, docx4j

I'm using Docx4j in eclipse to read XSLX files. I would like, from my `WorksheetPart`, to get the absolute size of my table.

For example if I have cells `A3`, `B3` and `D5` with a value, I would like to get :

- latestColumn = 4 (and not 3)
- latestRow = 5 (and not 2)

Is there a way to do this easily? In the `WorksheetPart` object this information seems to be missing.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to get the latest row but not the latest column (you need to compute it from cells names).

In more detail, here is an example of what I did to solve this.

You can get your file like this:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("Path/to/my/file.xlsx"); 
SpreadsheetMLPackage xlsxPackage = SpreadsheetMLPackage.load(is);
WorkbookPart wb = xlsxPackage.getWorkbookPart();
```

Let's say we want to work with the first sheet of your file:

```
int indexSheet = 0;
List<org.xlsx4j.sml.Row> rowsList = wb.getWorksheet(indexSheet).getContents().getSheetData().getRow();
```

Then, to get your latest row you can use getR which gives you the corresponding Excel row number:

```
Long lastRowIndex = rowsList.get(rowsList.size() - 1).getR();
```

To get the latest column number you need more work. First, you need a way to convert column name to integer (so that AB is 28 for example). You can do something like this:

```
private Integer computeColumnIndex(String cellName) {

    String columnLetters = cellName.replaceAll("\\d","");

    double sum = Double.valueOf(0);
    int len = columnLetters.length();
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        sum += (columnLetters.charAt(i) - 'A' + 1)*Math.pow(26,  len-i-1) ;
    }

    return (int)sum;
};
```

Then, for each row, you can compute the columnIndex of the latest cell of the row and keep the greatest :

```
int lastColumnIndex = 1;
for(org.xlsx4j.sml.Row row: rowsList) {

    String cellName = Iterables.getLast(row.getC()).getR();
    int columnIndex = computeColumnIndex(cellName);

    lastColumnIndex = Math.max(lastColumnIndex, columnIndex);           
}
```